# text-decoration not working for visited state link

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, text-decorations

I'm new on **CSS** and trying to understand how links are modified due to the changed state. On my scenario, I want to change the `text-decoration` to the `line-through` when the link is on **visited** state. However, neither on *Mozilla* nor *Chrome* browser, `text-decoration` of the text content not updated with `line-through` when the link is on **visited** state, shown as below. Where did I go wrong?

Please notify that the color is updated (to green) when the link state changed to **visited** while the `text-decoration` stays the same (see. Demo #1);

Note: There is a bug report for the Mozilla about the same issue: [Mozilla Bug #645786](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=645786) and on the bug report. Problem also reproduce for the `tag.class:state` **selector** (a.:visited)  (see **Demo #2**)

## Demo #1

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            a:link {
                color: red;
                text-decoration: none;
            }

            a:visited {
                color: green;
                text-decoration: line-through;
            }

            a:hover {
                color: blue;
            }

            a:active {
                color: yellow;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
            <b>
                <a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">This is a link</a>
            </b>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

## Demo #2 --Selector With Class

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            a.linkClass:link {
                color: red;
                text-decoration: none;
            }

            a.linkClass:visited {
                color: green;
                text-decoration: line-through;
            }

            a.linkClass:hover {
    color: blue;
            }

            a.linkClass:active {
    color: yellow;
            }
        </style>
 </head>
    <body>
        <p>
            <b>
                <a class="linkClass" href="http://google.com" target="_blank">This is a link</a>
            </b>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think it has something to do with: http://dbaron.org/mozilla/visited-privacy.. text-decoration is no option voor styling the 'visited-state'..

Comment: Weird, if so, why then the color is updated but not the text-decoration property? BTW are you netherlander? You've used 'voor' instead of 'for' :)

Comment: Ha, yeah I'm Dutch.. I didn't read it thoroughly, but it seems there's just a few properties that can be uses on :visited state (color, border/outline etc.)..

Comment: I've seen that privacy issue restrictions just a few mins ago and yes, text-decoration is out of the permitted style property list.

Answer (score 9):

There is a limitation for styling the visited links;

> Limits to visited link styles
>
> You will still be able to visually style visited links, but there are
>   now limits on what styles you can use. Only the following properties
>   can be applied to visited links:
>
> ```
> color
> background-color
> border-color (and its sub-properties)
> outline-color
> The color parts of the fill and stroke properties
> ```

[Privacy and the :visited selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Privacy_and_the_:visited_selector)

`text-decoration` styling is not permitted due to the user's privacy issues.

Comment: 100% accurate, your answer could have saved me alot of time. :)
A shame that Webkit and Firefox's CSS inspectors mark `:visited` properties [other then the ones you mentioned] as applied while it doesn't in this case.

Answer (score 2):

You can done with this jquery `addClass`.

**Demo code**

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('visited');
});
```

**CSS**

```
.visited {
  color: green;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

fiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/nikhilvkd/7y2fyytw/

Comment: Hi , you have put them in proper order , a:link              { color:yellow; }
a:visited           { color:red; }
a:hover             { color:pink; }
a:active            { color:black; }

Comment: I'm not searching for a jQuery answer, my point is to learn the pure htm/css solution. The question is tagged with html/css and this is a very basic, primitive property of CSS.

Comment: @Srinivas R : Already visited comes after the link property ?

Comment: @LeventDivilioglu In order to be effective , remember a:hover must come after a:link & a:visited in the CSS definition . it follow the love/hate principles .please go through this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/569268/avisited-doesnt-work-in-mozilla-firefox

Comment: @Srinivas R : Even I've got LV (which is partially proper), I've also added the Hover and Active states and it's still the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">google</a>
<style>
a:link             
 {  
color:red;
 }
a:visited    
    { color:yellow;
}
a:hover     
      { color:blue; }
a:active            { color:orange; }
</style>
```

Comment: This is not the case, the problem occurs for text-decoration property on visited state.

Comment: text-decoration property  did not work correct in visited code . which ignores the text-decoration property . pls go through this link   https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=645786