# Strike-through on click

Tags: html, css

Is there a css-way to make a `onclick` strike-through button. So when you click a button(piece of text) selected links will get the strike-through `text-decoration`?

Attached image as explanation.

[image]

Comment: Only with css is not possible, you need use JavaScript

Comment: However not recommended it is, It's still possible to do this with a checkbox hack isn't it?

Comment: @ChunYin - You are right. See my solution below. Look mom, no javascript!

Comment: you got many answer.pick which one you want @Jeppe Pendrup

Comment: @Gerard yep, was about to post that one but you got ahead of me so I upvoted you instead :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pure CSS simulating a button. When clicked, the paragraph turns red with strikethrough.

```css
input[id=cb] {
  display: none;
}

input[id=cb]:checked~p.strikethrough {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  color: red;
}

label {
  border: thin solid darkgray;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<input name="cb" type="checkbox" id="cb">
<label for="cb">Click me</label>
<p class="strikethrough">Paragraph 1</p>
<p>Paragraph 2</p>
<p class="strikethrough">Paragraph 3</p>
```

Answer (score 5):

> You can achieve this on any element using JS. **Also, not only you can
>   strike `onClick` but also remove the striked content back to its
>   original state.**

```js
$(function(){
  var $curParent, Content;
  $(document).delegate("span","click", function(){
    if($(this).closest("s").length) {
      Content = $(this).parent("s").html();
      $curParent = $(this).closest("s");
      $(Content).insertAfter($curParent);
      $(this).closest("s").remove();
    }
    else {
      $(this).wrapAll("<s />");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<span>click</span>/<span>click</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

With CSS only is not possible since [**`a:visited`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:visited) allows only to change:

- [**`color`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color?v=control)
- [**`background-color`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-color?v=control)
- [**`border-color`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-color) (and its sub-properties)
- [**`outline-color`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline-color)
- The color parts of the fill and stroke properties

<sub>[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35037025/1685157)</sub>

[**`text-decoration`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration?v=example) styling is not permitted due to the user's [privacy issues](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Privacy_and_the_:visited_selector).

---

Solution with jQuery:

```
$("a").click(function() {
  $(this).css("text-decoration", "line-through");
});
```

```js
$("a").click(function() {
  $(this).css("text-decoration", "line-through");
});
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">link</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [wrap](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) function we can insert an HTML structure around the inner elements like below:

```js
$('input[type=button]').click(function() {
  $('a').wrap("<strike>");
  //$('a').css("text-decoration", "line-through");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='button' id='but' value='Click'>
<a href="#">link</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
button:visited,
button:focus,
button:active {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <button>strike text onclick</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `line-through` effect doesn't go away on subsequent clicks.