# text-decoration-line doesn't work for links

Tags: html, css

```
a:visited {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

so I 've been trying to make the visited links turn into links with lines through it. But
it doesn't work. Other css type selectors like

```
a:hover {
    color: red;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

works just fine. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [text-decoration not working for visited state link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35031032/text-decoration-not-working-for-visited-state-link)

Answer (score 1):

Styling of visited links is **highly** restricted by design.

[**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited)

> For privacy reasons, browsers strictly limit which styles you can apply using this pseudo-class, and how they can be used:
>
> Allowable CSS properties are `color, background-color, border-color, border-bottom-color, border-left-color, border-right-color, border-top-color, column-rule-color, outline-color, text-decoration-color`, and `text-emphasis-color`.