# text decoration line-through for visited links

Tags: html, css, stylish

I tried different variations of this code fo Stylish:

```
a:visited {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

What i need to do for "line-through" visited links?

Comment: don't understand

Answer (score 0):

I found this by using `addEventListener("click"...)`

```js
document.getElementById("link1").addEventListener("click",function(){
document.getElementById("link1").style.textDecoration = "line-through";
});

document.getElementById("link2").addEventListener("click",function(){
document.getElementById("link2").style.textDecoration = "line-through";
});
```

```html
<a href="#" id="link1">Link 1</a>
<a href="#" id="link2">Link 2</a>
```

EDIT: Warning `text-decoration` styling is not permitted due to the user's privacy issues.

src: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Privacy_and_the_:visited_selector

**Limits to visited link styles**

You can style visited links, but there are limits to which styles you can use. Only the following styles can be applied to visited links:

- color
- background-color
- border-color (and its sub-properties)
- column-rule-color
- outline-color
- The color parts of the fill and stroke attributes

Comment: Thanks, but i need for all visited links

Comment: Sorry but then it's impossible: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Privacy_and_the_:visited_selector

Comment: Can read this question too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35031032/text-decoration-not-working-for-visited-state-link