# CSS Link: Why only "Visited" is not working

Tags: css, hover

My Firefox is not showing the color for visited links:

```css
a:link {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
  color: green;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: cyan;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

a:active {
  color: yellow;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<A HREF="https://stackoverflow.com/" TARGET="_parent">Test</A>
```

The Link text is shown in blue, hitting it with the cursor changes to magenta, clicking it for a short time yellow  - and after that blue again.
Where to find the problem?
Thank you.

Comment: Works for me. Aren't you rewriting the rules elsewhere by mistake?

Comment: Check with Inspect or (F12) in your browser

Comment: There is nothing except the code shown. Potentially a browser issue? What can be seen with F12?

Comment: check this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569268/avisited-doesnt-work-in-mozilla-firefox#:~:text=Go%20to%20Tools%20%2D%3E%20Options%20and,links%20do%20not%20change%20color.

Comment: No, in my case  - as shown -  visited is the second entry.

Answer (score 0):

It is related on the browser's chronic: This option must be activated, to see different colors! It's not really logical, as in an active session the pages visited can be seen by Menu > Chronic, even if that option is INactiv. Anyway, now it works!